# .net core package dependencies

Tags: .net, dependencies, .net-core

I'm wanting to build a native .NET Core executable that I can deploy but when I publish the project, the compiler exports all the dependencies into the same directory and the executable needs them to run on a system that doesn't have .NET Core runtime installed. Is there a way to compile/package the DLL's in with the project DLL or executable? Thanks.

Comment: Why does it have to be just one file?

Comment: For a portable binary release.

Comment: I think that's an oxymoron. You can't really have a portable binary release, because every platform has different binary file format.

Comment: Portable doesn't mean cross platform. It means ready to run wherever it is (within a build environment its designed for). I.e without needing runtimes / dependencies / libraries. The program shouldn't need an installer to allow it to run (needing register entries etc), it should all be self contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For merging dependencies into the compiled assembly, check out Costura for Fody:

https://github.com/Fody/Fody

https://github.com/Fody/Costura

I've used it before, and it works well. You can define certain dependencies to merge in a file called **FodyWeavers.xml** (*see the Costura-Fody link for examples*).

So, for example (*taken from the Costura README.md*) you can have two dependencies 'Foo' and 'Bar' that can be merged into your target assembly as follows in the FodyWeavers.xml file.

```
<Costura>
    <IncludeAssemblies>
        Foo
        Bar
    </IncludeAssemblies>
</Costura>
```

Other than that, ILMerge is a fine way to go: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge

**EDIT:** Found a link describing deploying required .NET core dependencies in a self-contained application: http://druss.co/2016/08/deploy-and-run-net-core-application-without-installed-runtime-self-contained-applications/

Comment: I was looking for a more in house solution within the .NET Core framework but this solution will work just as well. I already tried building a self contained executable but all that does is include the runtime libraries into the binary and exports the DLL's into the export location. This means that if you try running the executable outside of a directory of its dependencies then it will return an "Error: Missing assembly" message. I don't know if this is intentional or if .NET Core is actually supposed to bind the dependencies into the build. 

Thanks for the answer.